# ACL inheritance in Linux: create subdirectory with 700 rights for multiple users

Tags: linux, security, access-control-list

If I understand correctly this picture http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/ACL/img1.gif from this manual http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/ACL/POSIX_ACL_on_Linux.html, setting `700` via chmod will make

```
user::rwx
mask::---
other::---
```

(and actually it makes so).

But that means that I can't make directory and 2 or more users such that subdirectories will be with `700` rights for every user in ACL's `default`. 
It follows from fact that `user:some_user:...` and `group:someuser:...` will be intersected with mask (in this case with 0 and result will be also 0).

Am I right?

Simple example:
MySQL creates directories for databases with `0700` rights. And I want to make backup from my user (neither `mysql` nor `root`). It means that I want get `700` rights for my `mysqlbackup` user for subdirectories created by `mysql` user in MySQL direcrory. MySQL creates them while creating databases.

```
root@248261c6cbcc:/var/lib/mysql# getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: mysql
# group: mysql
user::rwx
user:mysqlbackup:rwx
group::---
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:mysqlbackup:rwx
default:group::---
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---

root@248261c6cbcc:/var/lib/mysql# sudo -u mysql -H mkdir -m 700 it_must_be_database_dir

root@248261c6cbcc:/var/lib/mysql# getfacl it_must_be_database_dir/
# file: it_must_be_database_dir/
# owner: mysql
# group: mysql
user::rwx
user:mysqlbackup:rwx        #effective:---
group::---
group:mysqlbackup:rwx       #effective:---
mask::---
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:mysqlbackup:rwx
default:group::---
default:group:mysqlbackup:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

As you can see, effective rights are `---`, nothing.

So, can I set ACL in such way that directories created with `700` will be accesible for `mysqlbackup` user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. Using 700 permissions, you are forcing a --- mask, and the system honors your directive.

You simply need to use a more permissive mask (eg: rwx) and control the effective access right via the ACL entries alone.